# Sort function for Activities in CaseView

Tags: civicase, activities

I want to sort the Activity Types that appear in the dropdown menue in CaseView, when clicking "Add Activity". It should be sorted according to a determined order (based on frequency of use).

Therefore, I built a custom sort function that I included in sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php:

```
  public function compareToSample($aTypes, $sample_array) {
    $new_array = array();
    $size_sample = count($sample_array);
    // search for first element of $samplearray in $atypes
    for ($newarrayindex = 0; $newarrayindex < $size_sample; $newarrayindex++) {
      $key = array_search($sample_array[$newarrayindex], $aTypes, FALSE);
      if($key) {
        // found an element -> save at the end of $new_array
        array_push($new_array, $aTypes[$key]);
        unset($aTypes[$key]); // delete it from $aTypes
      }
    }
    // if after the whole process $aTypes is not empty, add the rest of elements to end of $new_array
    if(!(empty($aTypes))) {
      if(empty($new_array)) {
        // no element in common
        return $aTypes;
      }
      else {
        $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $aTypes);
      }
    }
    return $new_array;
  }

public function mySort($array_to_sort) {
    $sample_array = array(...some string elements representing the activity types in the right order...);
    if(empty($array_to_sort)) {
      return null; // EXCEPTION
    }
    $result = $this->compareToSample($array_to_sort, $sample_array);
    return $result;
  }
```

I am calling this function with `$aTypes = $this->mySort($aTypes);` inside the `buildQuickForm()` function in CaseView.php. (I am calling it just after the place where the original code is also sorting `$aTypes`, that is, just after:

```
if (!$xmlProcessor->getNaturalActivityTypeSort()) {
      asort($aTypes);
    }
```

The problem is now that the function only seems to sort the *labels* of the Activity Types, but not the Types themselves. So when clicking on one type, it will create an activity with another type of the list. How can I get the function to sort the real elements?
Any hint is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my mistake was using the functions array_push and array_merge, as they assigned new keys to the array elements (activity types). Therefore, the single activity types couldn't be found in the following code anymore.

I changed these two expressions to:

```
$new_array[$key] = $aTypes[$key]; /// instead of: array_push($new_array, $aTypes[$key]);
```

and

```
$new_array = $new_array + $aTypes; /// instead of: $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $aTypes);
```

With that, it seems to work now.